# PDF File is corrupted when dowloaded via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a REST API  which must get a file from a remote URL in AWS servers.  The file is downloaded but when I try to open it, it shows nothing, like corrupted.

No exceptions are thrown

the code is this

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/[controller]/UploadFileToAzureStorage")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile([FromBody]PDF urlPdf)
        {
            string localFilePath = CreateTemporaryFile(urlPdf.urlPDF);

            // Create storage account
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageAccount);

            // Create a blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Get a reference to a container named "mycontainer."
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(UploaderStorage.Container);

            // Get a reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

            // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with the contents of a local file
            // named "myfile".
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
            {
                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }

            return Ok();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates temporary file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="urlPdf">PDF URL</param>
        /// <returns>Returns path of the new file</returns>
        private string CreateTemporaryFile(string urlPdf)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(urlPdf);
            string filename = default(string);
            //if (uri.IsFile)
            //{
                filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
            //}

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response =
                        client.GetAsync(urlPdf, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result)
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        using (Stream contentStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result, fileStream = new FileStream(@"\\pc030\TemporaryPDF\"+ filename,
                            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
                        {
                            var buffer = new byte[8192];
                            var isMoreToRead = true;
                            do
                            {
                                var read = contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).Result;
                                if (read == 0)
                                {
                                    isMoreToRead = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
                                }
                            }

                            while (isMoreToRead);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return @"\\pc030\TemporaryPDF\" + filename;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result` and `contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).Result` are a deadlock-bomb waiting to go off in your code.

**Never block by waiting on `Task.Result` in UI code or server code unless you fully understand the implications of doing so.**

Both server and UI use a special `SynchronizationContext` that schedules the async continuation back to the calling thread. When that same thread is already hung, waiting for `Result`, everything can lock-up.

Read and digest:

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Your `CreateTemporaryFile` method should be marked `async` and you should be `await`ing those calls.

So, to your problem. You're calling `fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read)` without `await`ing the Task's completion. On the (at least) last write, the stream will be disposed before the write is complete, with predicable results.

Adopt `async` ***properly*** or don't use it at all. There's no half-way house.